# How does Helm keep track of which Kubernetes cluster it installs to?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

If I am using [`kubectx`](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx) and switch kube config contexts into another cluster e.g. "Production" and run a `helm uninstall`, how does Helm know which cluster I am referring to?

If I run the `helm list` command is it only referring to what's installed on my local machine and not per Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Helm will default to using whatever your current Kubernetes context is, as specified in the `$HOME/.kube/config` file.

There is standard support in the Kubernetes API libraries to read data out of this file (or an alternative specified by a `$KUBECONFIG` environment variable).  If you're writing Go, see [the documentation for the `k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd` package](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd).  While `kubectx` does a bunch of things, [its core](https://github.com/ahmetb/kubectx/blob/master/cmd/kubectx/switch.go) uses that API to do essentially the same thing as running `kubectl config use-context ...`.

If you want Helm to use a non-default context, there is a [global option](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm/) to specify it:

```
kubectx production
helm list

kubectx development
helm --kube-context production list
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. How do you know if helm is using the default context or a non-default context?

Comment: If you don't use the `helm --kube-context` option then Helm uses the same rules (and the same underlying libraries) as the `kubectl` tool.